# Select max value from join Query

Tags: sql

This query results one column contains  many rows each cell contains a number:

```
SELECT B.Bil_Total_Remain
  FROM Bill_Sales B 
  JOIN Customer C ON B.Bil_Cus_Id=C.Cus_Id AND C.Cus_name = 'asd'
```

How can i retrieve the max  number in the Query's result?

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(B.Bil_Total_Remain) as your_max_value
from Bill_Sales B 
join Customer C on B.Bil_Cus_Id=C.Cus_Id 
                and C.Cus_name = 'asd'
```